# Laravel mutator do not set model attribute automatically

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

In My project there is a `PackageRequest` model and this model have a `tracking_code`.
I want to set this attribute automatically with a mutator.
this is my mutator:

```
 public function setTrackingCodeAttribute()
    {

        $code = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
        $this->attributes['tracking_code'] = "$code";
    }
```

but when I save new request into database there is no `tracking_code`

this is my part of code that create new PackageRequest:

```php
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->only(['requested_time', 'address_id']);
        $valid = validator($input, [
            'requested_time' => 'required|date',
            'address_id' => 'required|numeric|exists:addresses,id'
        ]);

        if ($valid->fails())
            return Response::fail($valid->errors());
        $package_request = new PackageRequest($input);
        $package_request->user_id = \Auth::id();
        $package_request->status = 'waiting';

        if(!$package_request->save())
            return Response::error(__('errors.save_data', ['attr' => __('errors.attribures.package_request')]));

        return Response::success(PackageRequest::find($package_request->id), 201);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The mutator will receive the value that is being set on the attribute, allowing you to manipulate the value and set the manipulated value on the Eloquent model's internal `$attributes` property.

The mutator will be automatically called when you attempt to set the value to attribute `tracking_code`, and you are not setting anything to it. What you need is setting default value to `tracking_code` before `creating`, so you can add these codes in model PackageRequest:

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($package_request)
    {
        $package_request->tracking_code = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
    });
}
```